# Как сохранить объект HTML

Tags: javascript, html

На странице есть контейнер div, а пользователь может его изменять - добавлять новые объекты. Как сделать, чтобы все эти добавленные объекты сохранить, а потом, когда пользователь зайдёт на страницу, все элементы восстановились??

Какие надо использовать функции, библиотеки, языки, чтобы реализовать это?

Comment: используйте LocalStorage

Comment: @дмытрык как использовать это с html-объектами?

Comment: Все зависит от конкретной задачи. В  localStorage можно просто хранить чистую информацию, а скриптом уже формировать html

Comment: А можно сериализовать весь DOM - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer

Comment: @Дмытрык а что значит "скриптом уже формировать html"?

Comment: `document.createElement`.... `innerText` .... и т.д

Comment: @Дмытрык короче говоря, я попробовал то, что вы сказали "скриптом уже формировать html". Исходя из вывода консоли, HTML-элемент тупо ломается, ибо вместо элемента "body" получается просто [object HTMLBodyElement], если использовать этот объект в функции .innerHTML, то вставляется пустой объект

Comment: @Дмытрык т.е., объект входит в loacalStorage объектом, а выходит из него уже ничем.

Comment: @Pon4iPay, в localStorage можно только строки записывать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const app = document.getElementById('app');
const serialazer = new XMLSerializer();

const strinElem = serialazer.serializeToString(app);
// const strinElem = document.body.innerHTML;  //так тоже будет работать но с нюансами


setTimeout(function() {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', strinElem )
  },2000)

//ниже код с использованием localStorage. Здесь не работает.

//localStorage.html = strinElem;
//setTimeout(function() {
  //const restoredElem = localStorage.html;
  //document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', restoredElem)
  //},2000)
```

```html
<div id="app">111</div>
```

Comment: как я не пытался, ничего не получилось. Но дело даже не в этом, а в том, что всё равно, что у меня на странице добавлялось, но обновляя её, всё слетает.

Comment: дополнил ответ кодом с использованием localStorage. Если что-то непонятно - почитайте документацию https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage или погуглите. Тема простая